# How to redirect your "Go to app" button to lead users to your website

Tags: facebook, web-applications

i set up a new app-- when my users recieve the permission scree, after clicking "Go to app" i want it to redirect to my own website (ex.www.mysite.com) instead its redirecting me to my website within facebook.

Since my website is not compatible within facebook, i need the app to lead users to my site- how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

The url that the users are being redirected to once the clicked the allow button is the url you provided in the "redirect_uri" parameter when you sent the user to the oauth dialog.

Instead of specifing your fb app url (apps.facebook.com/APP_NAME) you can use ex.www.mysite.com (as long as it's the same as what's in the app settings).

Another thing that you can do is to just reload the page using javascript:

```
top.location.href = "ex.www.mysite.com";
```

With all of that said, you should **not** be doing that.
It cleary says in the [Facebook Platform Policies](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/):

> 1. The primary purpose of your Canvas or Page Tab app on Facebook must not be to simply redirect users out of the Facebook experience
>      and onto an external site.

Answer (score 0):

If your app has a Canvas presence, then the Go To App button will redirect to your canvas landing page.  For example http://apps.facebook.com/yourapp

If your app is strictly a Connect app then the Go To App button will redirect to your site outside of Facebook for example http://www.yourapp.com

If your app has both Canvas and Connect implemented, it will go to the Canvas page.

The relevant settings in the Facebook developer app are under "Select how your app integrates with Facebook".  You do not need to have any canvas presence within Facebook.com.  You can just check the box for Website and then the Go To App button will take users directly to your site.  Be aware that if you do this you lose the ability to use a few important API features such as Bookmarks and Requests.